# ValidationEngine - Validation is bypassed when spaces are inserted

Tags: jquery

When only spaces are entered in required field, the validation is bypassed, it assumes that data has been entered in the field, wherein reality it is blank.

Any suggestions/solutions to this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery form validate not allow space for username field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942325/jquery-form-validate-not-allow-space-for-username-field)

Comment: i am using jquery validation engine
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice function for trimming leading and trailing whitespace ([API - jQuery Trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/))

```
jQuery.trim(stringToTrim);
```

Will return the string without the whitespace.

Note that you can accomplish this also with regular expressions.