# How can i validate number of words?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).
Is there any way to validate number of words?

For eg in "firstname" there shouldn't be any spaces allowed. So, the validating criteria shud be like this => maxwords="1"

Is there any way to do this currently? If not, what should i do to get this going.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942325/jquery-form-validate-not-allow-space-for-username-field. Refer this

Comment: +1 for the quick reply ;)

Comment: You really should make an attempt at this _before_ asking the question.

Comment: ok...but i guess the -1 was enuf to imply that! thanks neways

Comment: Firstly, you don't really know who voted, and secondly, it's always good to post a constructive comment when voting.

Comment: will kip that in mind, your second point ^_*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to create your custom rule.

Example:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("maxwords", function(value, element, params) {
    // your function to count words goes in here
    // use any of these arguments in your function: value, element, params
    // value => the present value of the field being tested
    // element => the present field being tested
    // params => the parameters passed in when you declare the rule.  
    // example:  // maxwords: 1  // params[0] would be 1
    // return true // if the field passes validation
    // return false // if the field fails validation and the message below will display
}, "Please enter at least {0} words."));
```